# Customising accessibility in recyclerview using onPopulateAccessibilityEvent and AccessibilityDelegate

Tags: android, kotlin, accessibility

I'm trying to customise the talkback output for items in a RecyclerView.  I have modified the `onBindViewHolder` method to include the following code

```
       itemView?.setAccessibilityDelegate(object: View.AccessibilityDelegate() {
            override fun onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host: View?, event: AccessibilityEvent?) {
                super.onPopulateAccessibilityEvent(host, event)
                event?.let {event ->
                    if (event.eventType == AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED) {
                        event.text.add("Hello world!")
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

Unfortunately, the talkback output is only modified for the last visible item in the `RecyclerView`.

I don't understand why the delegate works for some `ViewHolders` and not others.

Answer (score 4):

`RecyclerView` adds `AccessibilityDelegates` to its children to add its own actions to them. Since a View may have at most one delegate, whichever one is added first (yours or the one for `RecyclerView`) gets clobbered.

`RecyclerView` has its [own wrapper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.ItemDelegate) of `AccessibilityDelegate` that works for its children. That's what you want.

Comment: androidx link: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerViewAccessibilityDelegate.ItemDelegate