# android, accessibility talkback does not read when textView has clickable or focusable

Tags: textview, accessibility

having TextView like:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/_id"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:clickable="true" />
```

the talkback just does not read the text until remove the focusable and clickable.

searched and could not find if anyone also seeing this.

how to make it talkback readable and still allowing clicking?

Comment: That textview is missing `android:text="Some Text"` attribute. Seems like that is why `TalkBack` is not able to read it.

Comment: sorry, the text is dynamically filled in at binding time

Comment: In that case, you would have to send accessibility event after you set the text. Something like : `ViewCompat.sendAccessibilityEvent.TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT`, more info here:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/accessibility/AccessibilityEvent#TYPE_ANNOUNCEMENT

Comment: it does not make difference here. the view is one cell in the recyclerView. Expecting when the view scrolls in the talkback will read the textView one by one. But it does not when have the android:focusable="true" or android:clickable="true".  after remove these two, it starts to read them.    But if with the android:focusable="true", it will not read when scroll in, but when swipe on the view, it will start to read one and then read next if swipe again.

Comment: @Iannyf Sorry I couldn't help much. Maybe this answer will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446769/customising-accessibility-in-recyclerview-using-onpopulateaccessibilityevent-and/50478165